# re populate data to filepond from database laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel-blade, filepond

I'm trying get data from database and set into the filepond for preview and update the image, for update.
here is my code, but there is eror setFiles is not function. someone can help me to fix this

```
 var dataImg="{{ $existing_images }}"
    const pond = FilePond.create(document.querySelector('input[type="file"]'));
    const staticImageUrls = [dataImg]; // Replace with actual URLs
    pond.setFiles(staticImageUrls.map(url => ({ source: url })));
    pond.setOptions({
        acceptedFileTypes: ['image/png'],
        server:{
            allowMultiple: true,
            instantUpload: false,
            allowProcess: false,
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            },
        }
    })
```

thank you.

hope the image can retrive to filepond